# Activate window that is created with WS_EX_NOACTIVATE?

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a window that is created with the following CreateParams in C#:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams ret = base.CreateParams;
        ret.ExStyle |= (int) Windows.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The effect that I want from this is that it doesn't steal (keyboard) focus from other windows, yet still responds to mouse input.

**Question:**

How can I nevertheless activate, move and then deactivate it from code, when I want to move it using a mouse? I'm overriding `WndProc` and working with windows messages.

There must be window messages that should be able to do it. The sys command ["Move"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxxq8.png) does activate it, so it should be possible. But I need it to be much more simpler for users to move the window.

**Edit:**

I managed to activate and deactivate it with the following code but it doesn't move with the mouse (only changes its position on mouse up). The keyboard focus (caret) remains in the other window. That's what I need to keep intact, the focus in the other window.

```
SendMessage(m.HWnd, WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero); // activate
SendMessage(m.HWnd, WM_NCACTIVATE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); // deactivate
```

Comment: Not a message, it takes a method.  SetForegroundWindow() is the winapi function, if you use Winforms then you'd use Form.Activate()

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that works for moving (I managed to deactivate again too) but the keyboard focus is lost. Also see the edit please.

Comment: As I said, not a message.  The WM_NCACTIVATE message is a *notification*, it does not itself actually change the active window.  It is generated *because* the window activation changed.  Trying to fool code with a false notification has highly unpredictable outcomes.

Comment: @HansPassant I mixed myself a solution with the `Activate()` method, the `SetForegroundWindow()` function and an enumeration of windows to return the focus to the window before moving. Good tips! But you are wrong about [WM_ACTIVATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632633(v=vs.85).aspx). It **does** activate and deactivate the non-client-area of the window.

Comment: No, it makes it *look* like the window is activated.  It changes the caption colors.  The window is not in fact activated.  Don't fool code.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can set the focus window on the foreground thread, without activating its top-level parent window. To have the window move with the mouse you'll have to handle `WM_MOVING` messages and explicitly move the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two issues with WS\_EX\_NOACTIVATE and WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873729/two-issues-with-ws-ex-noactivate-and-winforms)